# Determining the equation of a rational function from its given 3 branches graph

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, graphing-functions, rational-functions

Note : definitely, *not* HW

---

Source: Chandler Unified School District ( Review Test , Rational functions, 2013-2014) : https://www.cusd200.org/cms/lib7/IL01001538/Centricity/Domain/1586/Review_for_Rational_Functions_Test_2013-2014.pdf

The graph is :

[image]

Let's write the desired equaton as : $\frac {P(x)} {Q(x)}$.

We need 2 vertical asymptotes , at $x=2$ and $x=-3$ . So $Q(x)= ( x-2) (x+3)$.

We need $2$ zeros , at $x=-4$ and $x=-1$. So , let's write $P(x)$ as $ k (x+4) (x+1)$.

Since we need a horizontal asympote $y=2$, let's set $k=2$.

Consequently we arrive at :

$f(x)= \frac {P(x)} {Q(x)} = \frac {2 (x+4) (x+1)} { ( x-2) (x+3)}$.

But that does not work :

[image]

(1) The concavity of the middle branch is not oriented to the right side

(2) The left branch follows its asymptote to $- \infty$ while it should increase indefinitely upwards.

> What do I miss and what can I do to correct  the inadequate
> features of the curve I obtain?

Comment: Try it with $(x-2)^2$ in the denominator, and $(x+4)^2$ in the numerator.

Comment: To elaborate on **Gerry Myerson**'s comment, the $ \ x-$intercept at $ \ x \ = \ -4 \ $ is a "touching" intercept (the sign of the function does not change on either side of the intercept), so the factor $ \ (x+4) \ $ must have an _even_ exponent.  Similarly, the function "runs to positive infinity" on both sides of the vertical asymptote at $ \ x \ = \ 2 \ \ , \ $ so the factor $ \ ( x - 2 ) \ $ must _also_ have an _even_ exponent.  (Had the graph shown, say, the value of the $ \ y-$intercept, that would have tipped you off that your factors weren't quite right...)

Comment: [continued from previous comment] Note that this keeps the degree of the polynomials in the numerator and in the denominator equal, so you will still have a horizontal asymptote.   (The sketched graph takes liberties with scale and doesn't show that the $ \ y-$intercept is actually _above_ the horizontal asymptote.)